# WSO2ESB - API Logging everything twice

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-esb

I've been working on an API to test a platform I've been involved with on my project at work and, after coming back from Christmas break, I notice that it's suddenly logging everything twice and I'm not sure why - if anyone could suggest a reason for this and how to stop it from doing it, that'd be much appreciated.  Examples below.

**The code:**

```
<iterate expression="//tests">
    <target>
      <sequence>
        <switch source="//tests/type">
          <case regex="GW">
            <log level="custom">
              <property name="TYPE" value="GW"/>
            </log>
            <send>
              <endpoint>
                <http trace="disable" uri-template="http://localhost:8280/testsuite/node/gw"/>
              </endpoint>
            </send>
          </case>
          <case regex="ESB">
            <log level="custom">
              <property name="TYPE" value="ESB"/>
            </log>
            <send>
              <endpoint>
                <http trace="disable" uri-template="http://localhost:8280/testsuite/node/esb"/>
              </endpoint>
            </send>
          </case>
          <case regex="MB">
            <log level="custom">
              <property name="TYPE" value="MB"/>
            </log>
            <send>
              <endpoint>
                <http trace="disable" uri-template="http://localhost:8280/testsuite/node/mb"/>
              </endpoint>
            </send>
          </case>
          <default>
            <log level="custom">
              <property name="OOPS" value="NODE DOESN'T EXIST"/>
            </log>
          </default>
        </switch>
      </sequence>
    </target>
  </iterate>
```

**The logs:**

```
[2016-01-13 09:29:17,331]  INFO -  STRT = STARTING TESTSUITE IN SEQUENCE {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
[2016-01-13 09:29:17,332]  INFO -  STRT = STARTING TESTSUITE IN SEQUENCE {API_LOGGER.JLRWSO2TestSuiteAPI}
[2016-01-13 09:29:17,334]  INFO -  TYPE = ESB {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
[2016-01-13 09:29:17,340]  INFO -  STRT = STARTING ESB IN SEQUENCE {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
[2016-01-13 09:29:17,341]  INFO -  STRT = STARTING ESB IN SEQUENCE {API_LOGGER.testesb}
[2016-01-13 09:29:17,345]  INFO -  STRT = STARTING TESTSUITE OUT SEQUENCE {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
[2016-01-13 09:29:17,346]  INFO -  STRT = STARTING TESTSUITE OUT SEQUENCE {API_LOGGER.JLRWSO2TestSuiteAPI}
[2016-01-13 09:29:17,346]  INFO -  To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:aafbecb4-c2fd-4d04-a64a-3e4bf1a63e50, Direction: response, Envelope: OK1 {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
[2016-01-13 09:29:17,347]  INFO -  ENDO = ENDING TESTSUITE OUT SEQUENCE {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
[2016-01-13 09:29:17,347]  INFO -  ENDO = ENDING TESTSUITE OUT SEQUENCE {API_LOGGER.JLRWSO2TestSuiteAPI}
```

From what I can tell, with my limited knowledge and experience of API development, the logs are coming from two different sources.  I don't know how to stop one of them so it just logs once, and I wouldn't know which to stop even if I knew how.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by switching the API_LOGGER.testapi to False from the Carbon GUI console.

[image: Switched API_LOGGER.testapi to false]

Answer (score 0):

Edit repository/conf/log4j.properties and add those lines at the end :

```
log4j.category.org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator=OFF
log4j.additivity.org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator=false
```

You must restart the ESB